# Conversion of H2O flow model to Python script

Tags: python, h2o

I am new to H2O and Python. I have designed a deep learning model in H2O flow. Can I convert same model in Python directly? I am looking for the python code behind my H2O flow model.

Answer (score 1):

Flow and Python are different ways how to use H2O platform so you cannot directly export the Flow notebook into Python, but you can very easily rewrite it into Python as the underlying functionality (calls to the platform) are the same. Have a look at the [demo](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-py/demos/deeplearning.ipynb) or the [Python API Booklet](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/booklets/PythonBooklet.pdf).